# Sinch In-App Instant Messaging

Tags: android, sinch

Sinch In-App Instant Messaging works perfectly fine with Sinch Managed Push but except this one issue.

This is the sistuation - I receives messages using GCM Listener when my app is foreground or background and I show notification but except in the case when my app is not running.

I inserted debug logs statements to see the flow and it seems that push message arrives in the GCM Listener and gets sent to my service as well but it never gets relayed to the message client listener. This only happens when the app is not running or is closed.

I am doing the following when the app is running background or foreground and I do get callback in onIncomingMessage but same code doesn't work when app is not running.

Sinch Client Initialization Code:

```
            public void startSinchClient(String username) {
            try {
                sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this).userId(username).applicationKey(ApplicationConstants.SINCH_SANDBOX_API_KEY)
                        .applicationSecret(ApplicationConstants.SINCH_SANDBOX_API_SECRET).environmentHost(ApplicationConstants.SINCH_SANDBOX_API_URL).build();

                sinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
                sinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(true);

                sinchClient.checkManifest();

                sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);

                if ( messageClientListener == null ) {
                    messageClientListener = new MyMessageClientListener();
                }

                sinchClient.getMessageClient().addMessageClientListener(messageClientListener);
                Log.e("SinchMessageService", "Login successful.");
            } catch (MissingGCMException missingGCM) {
                Log.e("SinchMessageService", missingGCM.getMessage());
            }
            }
```

OnBind Code

```
            if (!isSinchClientStarted()) {
                startSinchClient(currentUserId);
                sinchClient.start();
            }
```

In RelayRemotePushNotificationCode:

```
            public NotificationResult relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(Intent intent) {
            if ( currentUserId.isEmpty() ) {
                Log.e("SinchMessageService", "UserID not available.Please login again.");
                return null;
            } else if ( !isSinchClientStarted() ) {
                startSinchClient(currentUserId);
                sinchClient.start();
            }

            Log.d("SinchService", "relayRemotePushNotificationPayload");

            NotificationResult notificationResult = sinchClient.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(intent);

            if (notificationResult.isMessage()) {
                sinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
            }

            return notificationResult;
            }
```

In MessageClientListener:

```
                            public void onIncomingMessage(MessageClient client, final Message message) {
            if (message.getRecipientIds().get(0).equals(ApplicationConstants.userInfo.getEmail())) {
                sinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
            ....
```

The above code works in all the scenarios. I mean when the app is running in foreground as well as background. Only when I kill the app never get the onIncomingMessage callback.

Log statements from Sinch Client:

**03-03 22:07:44.213 17381-17381/com.ontyme E/SinchClient: mUserAgent.startBroadcastListener()**

**03-03 22:07:45.271 17381-17381/com.ontyme E/MessageClient: onIncomingMessage: NativeMessage [id=2059913a-27ac-4105-a797-764f09af66d2, nativeAddress=-1321533856]**

Anyone else has faced the issue?

Comment: How are you implementing the whole sinchClient? is it with the approach we have in the sample apps with a service? As soon as the app becomes active/launched you should make sure the the sinch client it started just as you start it when you first login and hook in all the listeners etc. From your code aboeve I cant tell if you already set up the client.

Comment: @cjensen I edited my original post with code snippets.

Comment: From you log it looks like onIncomingMessage is called, can it be that it crashes because you try to access UI here?

Comment: Thanks @cjensen. Nope service has no UI code and I don't think even that would matter reason I am saying this because I have log statements in the beginning of onIncomingMessage which is ideally the entry point but they never get called which means callback is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys there is no problem with the Sinch Managed Push. It was small typo at my end which was causing this issue. My receipentid in the app was not getting initialized correctly when the app was not running which is why all the messages were getting ignored in onIncomingMessage.

Managed Push works seamlessly for me now.